# How to remove tool bar in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, toolbar

I would like to remove the tool bar from my theme since I don't have that many products.

So far I have tried this in my `/app/design/frontend/VENDORNAME/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
    <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" remove="true"/>
```

Also I tried to replace `/app/design/frontend/VENDORNAME/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/pager.html` with a empty file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing the toolbar can be done in current theme dir by commenting in

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

the 2 lines with

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

To hide it only in category page than wrap getToolbarHtml() with an if statement.

```
<?php if (!$this->getMyHideFlag()): ?>
  <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In custom module's layout/catalog_category_view.xml add 'my_hide_flag' argument (or use layout instruction `<action>`). Set this 'my_hide_flag' to 1.
Reference the block 'category.products.list'.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Toolbar block is called in

```
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList::_beforeToHtml.
```

Removing the toolbar and than calling toolbar block object in _beforeToHtml may trigger fatal errors.

Or hide the toolbar from css/less.
Magento default css/less hides sorter, limiter, pages and view mode in top and bottom tollbars.

Comment: I have tried hiding sorter from css but its not working.

Answer (score 6):

Add it to `catalog_category_view.xml` layout in you custom theme

```
/app/design/frontend/VENDORNAME/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout‌​/
```

Then clear cache and toolbar will disappear

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" remove="true" />
```

Comment: please try to describe your answer. And if you are not sure with your answer its better to write a comment instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: Perfectly normal answer! the only thing, replace display="false" with remove="true" and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to change the template file of the toolbar.

Create a new blank file in
`/<theme_dir>/Magento_Catalog/templates/blank.phtml`

Update the toolbar template via `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::blank.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```