# How to remove breadcrumbs from category page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am messing with an issue in Magento 2 site. I have to remove breadcrumbs from the category page. I have also to remove the toolbar from the same page.

[image]

Comment: you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add below code to remove breadcrumbs from category pages

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

> `<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />`

For remove toolbar

> `<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" display="false" />`

Remove **var/cache** and **var/page_cache** folder.

Thank you for the information this was helpful. 
**For Magento 2.2.5** use the code below

> `<referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />`

Comment: Baffles me how something so simple needs to be done with code instead of just through the admin panel.

Answer (score 7):

Add below code to remove breadcrumbs from category pages

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

And for removing toolbar, Comment out below line form list.phtml

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

the 2 lines with

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

[You can see more here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102887/how-to-remove-tool-bar-in-magento-2)

Comment: I have to remove toolbar also in same page

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: If my solution is works for you, Accept my answer.

Comment: Toolbar is not getting hidden

Comment: I have added the picture

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61358/discussion-between-s-h-patel-and-amrit-pal-singh).

Comment: Try this : <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" display="false" /> and let me know if works for you.

Comment: tried with false also and clear cache also still not worked

Comment: <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" display="false"  /> this will works but you need to remove var/cache folder and check.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

and put below code in `<body>` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" display="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below code in your layout file **catalog_category_view.xml** file.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this

```
 <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

breadcrumbs builds page title and meta tags

better use this way

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::extra/empty.phtml" />
```

create empty file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/extra/empty.phtml
```

Comment: It's better to use `<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" display="false" />` it does the same and works well, Anyway, thank you so much for the hint